# Ubuntu global menu bar integration?

Tags: front-end, ubuntu, menu

Is there a way to integrate the Mathematica menu bar into the Ubuntu Unity global menu bar at the top of the screen? (I'm not looking to run mini-applications.) Thanks!

Comment: Since you did not receive an answer to this question perhaps you would do well to try it on SuperUser?  Since this has something to do with OS interaction it's possible a generic method is available.

Answer (score 2):

*Mathematica* ships with it's own Qt libraries. Consider replacing them with the system libraries, then it probabily fits nicely into the Ubuntu layout.

This guide will probabily also workk with newer *Mathematica* versions:

http://homepage.uibk.ac.at/~c705283/archives/2010/03/29/mathematica_7_qt_style/index.html

Comment: I tried this guide but it didn't help me with _Mathematica 9_. I could not even find the `Qt-Plugins` directory in my Mathematica installation folder, and the line calling `"${MathematicaFE}"` doesn't bother about my chosen Qt `-style` option.